# A script to add 1 to part of a URL

Tags: javascript

I am very new to JavaScript but I want to make a script that will add 1 to a number in a URL whenever I click a button. (I also want my browser to open each newly created URL each time the function is carried out if that's possible).

I think this has to use `str.replace` and I wrote some kind of function out but it will not work yet and I'm not sure how my browser could open the new variables each time I run the function.

The function I made (in an HTML document) is below, so do you know how it can be edited to do what I would like? I could provide more information if needed of course. Thank you!

```
function {
  var str = http://www.example.com/static/page/test/test.jhtml?channelID=11&seriesID=0&episodeNumber=001
  var res = str.replace("(seriesID=)", "(seriesID=) + 1)");
}
```

Comment: You need to go through the fundamentals in-depth, 'cause your code's all over the place: 1) `function` needs a name and parentheses. 2) The URL needs to be enclosed in quotes. 3) Also, read how `str,replace` actually works.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function setSeriesID(url, id) {
  // var pattern = /(seriesID\=\d)/g;
  var pattern = /(seriesID\=\d+)/g; // edited 
  
  return url.replace(pattern, 'seriesID=' + id);
}

var new_url_1 = setSeriesID('http: //www.example.com/static/page/test/test.jhtml?channelID=11&seriesID=0&episodeNumber=001', 1);

alert("new_url_1 : " + new_url_1);

// otherwise if you want to change multiple url params then use this :

function set_id(parameter, url, id) {
  // var pattern = new RegExp("(" + parameter + "\\=\\d)", 'g');
  var pattern = new RegExp("(" + parameter + "\\=\\d+)", 'g'); // edited 
  return url.replace(pattern, parameter + '=' + id);
}

var new_url_2 = set_id('seriesID', 'http: //www.example.com/static/page/test/test.jhtml?channelID=11&seriesID=0&episodeNumber=001', 1);

alert("new_url_2 : " + new_url_2);
```

Comment: Is the `+` after seriesID correct? Doesn't that mean 1 or more D characters?

Comment: @PDN. Thanks just a mistake from me :)

Comment: in fact I was just going to suggest you add it: \d+, because most of them  popular series have over 10 episodes.

Comment: @BekimBacaj. Thanks, Approved your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The str seems not to be a string. Put '' around. The function is missing ().

```
    function name() {
      var str = 'http://www.example.com/static/page/test/test.jhtmlchannelID=11&seriesID=0&episodeNumber=001';
      var res = str.replace("(seriesID=)", "(seriesID=) + 1)");
      console.log(res);
}

name();
```

The use of replace does not work like that.

Answer (score 0):

Three problems with your function.

First, the str is not actually a string, you'll need quotes around it for it to be a valid string.

```
  var str = "http://www.example.com/static/page/test/test.jhtml?"channelID=11&seriesID=0&episodeNumber=001
```

Second, replace() will replace a substring with something else. In this case, it's searching for the literal string `"(seriesID=)"` which does not exist. Get rid of the parentheses: `"seriesID="`

Finally, when you add a number to a string, javascript will turn the number into a string and return a string. Therefore, after you click the button, the result will always be `"seriesID=1"`. To get around this, parse out the number and turn it into a number using `Number()` that you store in another `var number` that you add 1 to whenever you click the button. Finally, you'll call replace with:

```
 str.replace('seriesID=', 'seriesID=' + number);
```

Answer (score 0):

May look like a bit complicated, but this will do exactly what you need.

```js
var str = 'http://www.example.com/static/page/test/test.jhtml?channelID=11&seriesID=0&episodeNumber=001';

function myFun() {  
  
  var n = str.indexOf("seriesID");
  var m = str.indexOf("&",n);
  var y = str.substring(n, m);
  var z = y.split('=');
  
  str = str.replace(y, z[0] + '=' + (parseInt(z[1]) + 1));
  
  var win = window.open(str, '_blank');

  console.log(str);
  
  if(win){
    //Browser has allowed it to be opened
    win.focus();
  } else{
    //Broswer has blocked it
    alert('Please allow popups for this site');
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick='myFun()'>Click me</button>
```